# I Want to get a week value

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I wan to get the value of only one week. I am using the following JPA query:

```
 SELECT a 
 FROM questions.dao.hibernate.Questions a 
 WHERE (a.posted_date-CURRENT_DATE)>= 7
```

But I am getting an error message like

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: posted_date of: questions.dao.hibernate.Questions [SELECT a FROM questions.dao.hibernate.Questions a WHERE (a.posted_date-CURRENT_DATE)>=7]
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Accept some previous answers to your questions and provide more details on your hibernate mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds pretty self-explanatory to me. The class `questions.dao.hibernate.Questions` does not have a property called `posted_date` (it *may* have the property - that would be a strange naming convention though - but Hibernate doesn't know it).